# Linked list C++ not saving when using mutator to update the head's next

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I am new to C++ and working on setting up a linked list.
Why is the below code not updating the list's head's next. I get the following output

```
    void addToList(int dataToAdd){
        Node nodeToBeAdded(dataToAdd, NULL); //initilize the node we are going to add with the data that was given by the user

        if(this->getHead() == NULL){
            this->setHead(&nodeToBeAdded);
            cout << "Added " << this->getHead()->getData() << " to the head of the list\n";
            return;
        }
       //Calls this even after I set the heads next
        else if(this->getHead()->getNext() == NULL){
            cout<<"Test\n";
            this->getHead()->setNext(&nodeToBeAdded);
        }
        //IT NEVER REACHES THIS
        else{
            cout<<"super test\n";
        }

    }
```

I get the following output

```
Added 3 to the head of the list
Test
Test
```

Thanks

Comment: `nodeToBeAdded` -- What is the lifetime of that variable?

Comment: Before you attempt a linked list, play around with allocation on the heap, you will need it.

Comment: The point being that it isn't going to work storing the address of a variable that will go up in a puff of smoke when that function returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, your current output is correct and expected based on your current code.  The major problem I see is that your addition code only goes 1-2 steps past the head of the list when finding a point to insert a new node.  The general procedure you should be following is to walk down the list until you reach the end, and then add the new node there.  Something like this:

```
void addToList(int dataToAdd) {
    Node* curr = this->getHead();
    Node nodeToBeAdded(dataToAdd, NULL);

    // for an empty list assign the head and return
    if (curr == NULL) {
        this->setHead(&nodeToBeAdded);
        cout << "Added " << this->getHead()->getData() << " to the head of the list\n";
        return;
    }

    // otherwise walk down the list and insert the new node at the end
    while (curr->getNext() != NULL) {
        curr = curr->getNext();
    }

    curr->setNext(&nodeToBeAdded);

    return;
}
```